# Insert data into mySQL table with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a predefined table in a mySQL database: 
[image]

I am working on saving data inputted from the user to the database but I cant seem to any data to save in the database. With the following code I am trying to update the first row of the database (ID: 1 through OTHER 2: 0). What am I doing wrong?

```
private java.sql.Connection con = null;
private PreparedStatement pst = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/deliveryEarn";
private String user = "root";
private String password = "root";

try {
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
     Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement(); 

     st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO incomeCalc " + "VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)");

     con.close();
}

catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(deliveryMain.class.getName());
     lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

 }
```

Comment: If your not getting an error, change the SqlException to Exception and see what error you get

Comment: why use straight sql to do your insert and not a ORM like hibernate or Ibatis instead ?

Comment: Yes, It is better to use ORM like Hibernate or iBatis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it will not work because the number of values is less than the number of columns in your table. What you have to do is to specify the name of columns to match the number of your values.

```
INSERT INTO incomeCalc VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)  // error
// the only way this will work is when you have only 5 columns in 
// your table but in your case you have 7 that is why it will not work
```

it should be

```
INSERT INTO incomeCalc(specify columns here to the values bound to)
VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)
```

**[w3School: (INSERT)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)**

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two forms.

The first form doesn't specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your insert statement should be:

```
"INSERT INTO incomeCalc(ID, TIPS, HOURS, GAS, HOURLY_EARNINGS) " +
"VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)"
```

In other words your statement is missing column names.

Comment: Columnnames in an `INSERT` statement are optional, even though it is not wise to not specify them, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Column names are NOT optional if you have a insert statement with less columns than real column number in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the column names for example:

```
"INSERT INTO incomeCalc (ID, TIPS, HOURS, GAS, HOURLY_EARNINGS) VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)"
```

Answer (score 1):

**A**. Either pass the values for all the columns of the table in the order which they are defined in MYSQL DB. Here we can see 7 columns in your table and you are providing only 5 values...

or

**B**. Make use of this syntax

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAMES_SEPARATED_BY_COMMA) VALUES (VALUES_SEPARATED_BY_COMMA)
```

Answer (score 1):

like munyengm the statement in you rcase would be :
"INSERT INTO incomeCalc(ID, TIPS, HOURS, GAS, HOURLY_EARNINGS) " +
"VALUES (3, 75, 6, 25, 18.50)"

but you probably going to loop value and stuff so I would recommend using a prepared statement instead, this prevent sql injection.

```
ps = "INSERT INTO incomeCalc(ID, TIPS, HOURS, GAS, HOURLY_EARNINGS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

then

```
        ps.setInt(index++, id); //id=3
        ps.setInt(index++, tips); //tips=75
        ps.setInt(index++, hours);//hour=6
        ps.setInt(index++, gas);//gas=25
        ps.setFloat(index++, HOURLY_EARNINGS);
```

Answer (score 1):

First `READONLY = false;`

There are some restrictions.You need to put `[Name_table$]` and `\` before and after the `COLUMN_NAMES`. like this:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO [IncomeCalc$] (\"ID\", \"TIPS\", \"HOURS\", \"GAS\",\"HOURLY_EARNINGS\") VALUES ('2012-10-25 01:00:00','16.3')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This format worked for me like you see it, no extra commas, slashes or anything else was necessary:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO incomeCalc (value1, value2, value99) VALUES (3, 75, 6)");
```