# Inserting data into MY SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, insert, sqlcommand

I am trying to insert values retrieved from dictionary into Database but unable to do so,
my insert statement is as follows,

```
    String command="INSERT INTO TABLE1(elog_r)VALUES(@rV where id=@value);";

    where value of rV is

    rV=dict.get("VOLTAGE-VR");
```

In ASP.NET we can write as

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rV", rV);
```

I want the solution for the same in JAVA.

Comment: do you use javax.persistence? check http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904314/insert-data-into-mysql-table-with-java hope this helps

Comment: Please have look on prepared statements from docs..

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample from mykong website, which you can give you some hint about using the java JDBC to insert data in a table:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

You can  follow the complete tutorial here:

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/